# Vector of monomials in Julia

Tags: julia

I would like to write the vector of monomials `[1,x,y,z,x^2,xy,xz,y^2...,z^2]`. My main problem is to write the number 1 as a monomial, and not as integer.

Comment: Put the code inside backticks for readability like `\`[1,x,y,z,x^2,xy,xz,y^2...,z^2]\``.

Comment: Monomials are functions. In order to have a vector of monomials, you would need a vector of functions. Or you could represent monomials by a custom type, and then have a vector of objects that are instances of your monomial type. One way to write the monomial 1 as a function over a three dimensional domain is this: `(_, _, _) -> 1`